# Hiddenfield WebControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, hiddenfield

```
            foreach (var item in AnketSoru)
        {
            r = new HtmlTableRow();
            c = new HtmlTableCell();
            c.InnerHtml = item.new_question_text.ToString();
            r.Cells.Add(c);

            switch (item.new_question_type.ToString())
            {
                case "2": //FreeText
                    c = new HtmlTableCell();
                    TxtFreeText = new TextBox();
                    TxtFreeText.ID = "Txt_" + item.new_survey_questionid.ToString();
                    TxtFreeText.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
                    TxtFreeText.Width = 300;
                    TxtFreeText.Height = 50;
                    TxtFreeText.EnableViewState = true;
                    c.Controls.Add(TxtFreeText);

                    HiddenField txthfield = new HiddenField();
                    txthfield.Value = item.new_name.ToString();
                    c.Controls.Add(txthfield);
```

and

```
                foreach (Control c in plc.Controls)
            {
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable Survey_Inner = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable)c.FindControl("Survey_Inner");

                foreach (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow r in Survey_Inner.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (Control ctr in r.Cells)
                    {
                        foreach (Control ct in ctr.Controls)
                        {
                            if (ct.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox")
                            {

                                string freeTxtQues = ?? ;

                                string TextCevap = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)ct).Text;

                                string deger = ct.ID.ToString();



                                Guid QuestionId = new Guid(deger.Substring(4));

                                SaveAnswers(this._PortalUserHelper.UserProxy.ContactId, EgitimKatilimcisi, QuestionId, TextCevap, freeTxtQues);

                            }
```

i tryed

```
string freeTxtQues = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField)ct).Value;
```

but returns me error. "InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code."

'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' türündeki nesne 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField' türüne atılamadı.

I'm trying to reach hiddenfields value's and set them to the freeTxtQues value but couldn't able to do it for now. Any help for how can i do that?

Comment: Do you mean how to get the value(txthfield.Value)?

Comment: Not clear what the question/problem is, care to expand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to understand your question/problem but I will throw something...

When you create dynamic controls you need to create them on Init event so when ViewState is applied he finds the controls and sets their values. If you are not creating the controls in Init but later, you will found out that the control doesn't have the supposed value!

Comment: I'm sorry i've been hurry: What i want is set that string freeTxtQues values to hiddenfields value's. Hiddenfield values have my Survey Question text's and i want to write them as my survey_answer name's. So Each time freetext created a hiddenfield created and store my Question Text, and on Submit_Click i'm collect that string and send as my answer name at least i was trying this. i've problem at collecting part i tryed something but gives me error wrote that part above.

Comment: You are trying to cast TextBox's to HiddenFields since you are filtering the controls to TextBox's here `if (ct.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox")`. Also, use `ct.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)`, its more correct

Comment: i guess i've problem with finding hiddenfield controls. i tryed this and seems to be it works now.

"string TextHidden = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField)ctr.FindControl("hd_" + deger.Substring(4))).Value;"

Comment: That's also another way of searching it! Usually, when I do dynamic stuff, I end with a lot of controls so I avoid using the FindControl since it will iterate through the whole control list. I just create list's for the controls I will need to search and add them as I create them and then I just need to iterate the list.